# Working android code does not connect to apache (checked accesslog) but connects to amazon and google

Tags: android, apache

I have used below code earlier and it worked. Now it doesn't and it's not showing an error. Internet permissions are granted.

I expect the output login successful/Unsuccessful from server side.

My code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String login_url = "http://192.168.1.125/crown/login.php";
    String method = params[0];

    if(method.equals("login")){

        String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();


            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";

            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    return null;
}
```

Can someone please figure out where the problem lies?

Comment: tried localhost 10. ip too

Comment: php and mysql codes are working.

Comment: html and php scripts are giving desired outputs.